# I have a generic method that will not take the type I parameterized it to

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I would like to take the contents of the G.myUglyList list here and pass it to the Outer.send() method.  I do not understand why this gives a compiler error. ? extends Inner is the type I parameterize Outer with.  So why is it rejecting an Inner passed to it?  It wants a "? extends Inner", which isn't a type.

I want the list declared as `List<Outer<? extends Inner>>` so it can take subtypes of Inner.  (Please see the **edit** below for why this is)

```
interface Outer<T> {
    void send(T message);
}
interface Inner {}
interface Inner2 extends Inner {}

public class G {

    List<Outer<? extends Inner>> myUglyList;

    void foo() {
        Inner xxx = null;
        for (Outer<? extends Inner> outer : myUglyList) {
            outer.send(xxx); //error
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
error: method send in interface Outer<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
required: CAP#1
found: Inner<T#1>
reason: actual argument Inner<T#1> cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conversion
where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
T#1 extends Object declared in class G
T#2 extends Object declared in interface Outer
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Inner<T#1> from capture of ? extends Inner<T#1>
```

**edit**:  I got a lot of answers saying just make the list of type `List<Outer<Inner>>`, but that is incorrect.  I will *not* be able to add subtypes of Inner if I do that.  If I try to add an `Outer<Inner2>`, it would fail.  So list must be of type `List<Outer<? extends Inner>>`.

```
interface Inner2 extends Inner {}        
class G {
  void foo() {
    Outer<Inner2> foiled = null;
    myUglyList.add(foiled);   //this will fail if list is of type List<Outer<Inner>>
    Inner xxx = null;
    for (Outer<? extends Inner> outer : myUglyList) {
    outer.send(xxx); //error
  }
```

Comment: Note that the `List<Outer<? extends Inner>>` should be used as a type for a parameter that can handle `List<Outer<Inner>>` or `List<Outer<ClassThatImplementsInner>>`, not for attribute declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PECS - Producer `extends` Consumer `super`

Because `outer` is parameterized with `extends`, you cannot pass *anything* (except `null`) into its `send` method.

Comment: your answer gave me enough of a clue... Didn't know of PECS before.  I also found this gem which explains PECS in more detail.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs

Answer (score 3):

Change your code for:

```
interface Outer<T> {
    void send(T message);
}
interface Inner {}
interface Inner2 extends Inner {}

public class G {

    List<Outer<Inner>> myUglyList;

    void foo() {
        Inner2 xxx = null;
        for (Outer<Inner> outer : myUglyList) {
            outer.send(xxx); //error
        }
    }
}
```

And it will compile

**Update:**

```
// No matter if you put 'T extends Inner' here, the 'add' won't compile
interface Outer<T extends Inner> {
    void send(T message);
}
interface Inner {}
interface Inner2 extends Inner {}

public class G {

    List<Outer<Inner>> myUglyList;

    void foo() {
        Outer<Inner2> foiled = null;

        // This way, the 'add' invocation will compile, but it 
        // breaks the generic and generates a warning.
        //
        // Casting 'foiled' to (Outer<Inner>) will also fail
        // because the compiler sees Outer<Inner2> as complete different type
        // from Outer<Inner>
        myUglyList.add((Outer) foiled);  

        Inner xxx = null;
        for (Outer<Inner> outer : myUglyList) {
            outer.send(xxx); //error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Except that will not allow me to put in subtypes of Inner into Outer.  See my edit, please.

Comment: @marathon The compiler reads the wildcard as an unknown type (unknown but bounded), so `Outer<? extends Inner>` says that `outer` does not have a known type (almost as if it does't have any), that's why the compiler fails deducing the type for the `send` invocation, it doesn't have a matching type for the wildcard.

To solve the problem with the `add` invocation, you can write `myUglyList.add((Outer) foiled);`, it's messy and it will generate a warning though

Comment: You've tied Outer's parameter to Inner in Outer's declaration, which, in general might not be desired, if Outer is used elsewhere for other things, too.  If outer were actually say, java.util.Set, that wouldn't fly.

Comment: @marathon Yes, you're right, I put the `T extends Inner` part there just to emphasize that adding it won't work

Answer (score 2):

Just declare

```
List<Outer<Inner>> myUglyList;
```

You can then add subtypes of `Inner` without restriction. By declaring it

```
List<Outer<? extends Inner>> myUglyList;
```

you are saying that `myUglyList` is "a list of `Outer<some specific (but unknown) subtype of Inner>`". That's not what you want.

Comment: Except that will not allow me to put in subtypes of Inner into Outer.  See my edit, please.

Comment: @marathon - Yes, that is correct. Generally, you cannot mix types in a list and `Outer<Inner2>` is not a subtype of `Outer<Inner>` (even though `Inner2` is a subtype of `Inner`). However, an `Outer<Inner>` can accept an `Inner2` argument to `send`. Perhaps you can make do with that, or describe more about why that would not work for you. What are you trying to accomplish that requires mixing types?

Comment: @marathon - The technical issue you are facing is that generics in Java are not covariant. There's a nice article [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html) that describes the issue well.

Answer (score 2):

`outer` is of type `Outer<? extends Inner>`, i.e. of some unknown subtype of `Inner` and its `send` method takes an object of that same subtype.

For example `outer` may be of type `Outer<OtherInner>` and then `outer.send` needs a `OtherInner`, so `outer.send(xxx)` would be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (Outer<? extends Inner> outer : myUglyList) {
     outer.send(xxx); //error
 }
```

In that, `Outer<? extends Inner> outer`, so the actual type is unknown (`?`). `send` takes something unknown that extends `Inner`, and also `outer` has something that extends `Inner` but still unknown.

**Update**

```
interface Outer<T extends Inner> {
    void send(T message); //this can take instance of subtype of Inner
}
interface Inner {}
interface Inner2 extends Inner {}

class G {

    List<Outer<Inner>> myUglyList; //you can add instances of subtypes of Inner

    void foo() {
        Inner xxx = null;
        for (Outer<Inner> outer : myUglyList) {
            outer.send(xxx); //error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @marathon: See the update, I think with that your Outer can send anything that extends Inner and you can those anything to the list too.

Comment: but that forces Outer to be tied to Inner in Outer's declaration.  Pretend instead of outer that was Set<T>.  Outer might be used for non-Inner things.